# Keep collapse expand while exporting to PDF in SSRS 2008

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pdf-generation

I have designed a report with collpase-expand functionality in SSRS 2008, my requirement is to export the report in PDF, but I am not sure if it is possible to keep the collpase-expand feature alive while exporting to PDF. I google this but not found anything usefull.
Please help.

**ANY QUICK HELP**

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible in PDF format.  It works to a degree in Excel.

You could create bespoke versions of your report specifically for PDF exporting, and specify what should show in each one.